# C# Winforms Listbox filtering Datagridview by Date

Tags: c#, date, datagridview, listbox, format

So, I have an excel file with column "settlement date" with this format: dd/mm/yyyy. I send this over a SQL column within a "date" format where the format changes automatically in yyyy-mm-dd. Then when I send this SQL column to a C# Winforms listbox using:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rd.Read())
{
mylistbox.Items.Add(rd[0]);
}
```

the dates are displayed again in dd/mm/yyyy (the same format I had on excel) and eventually when I'm trying to filter a datagridview by settlement date using my listbox just filled, I've got the following error message:

```
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".
```

I read a few things so far but I'm a bit confused here, should I change the format directly from the start (excel table) to SQL server or maybe change within SQL from format "date" to "string" and once in winform, just sorting as it would be a string ?

Let me know if it doesn't sound very clear or you need more info

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dave Holden, I understood that my SQL SERVER has its dates in English where my windows applications (Excel,  C# winform) display dates in French/UE format. The code I need to use so that I can display French/UE format within my listbox and datagridview while filtering within the sql server US format:

```
C#
foreach (var li in lb.SelectedItems)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (li.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(li.ToString(), out dt))
        {
            strCondition += $"'{dt:yyyy-MM-dd}',";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strCondition += $"'{li}',";
    }
                     
}
```

So I actually loop within each listbox and I get each selected items.
I know it can be either string or date/datetime so the items selected are date/datetime then I turn it into string (first argument of TryParse has to be a string) to eventually have the output in plain datetime and I'll applied to it the "yyyy-mm-dd" that works within SQL Server.
So that, my users have the dates displayed in French but the app' will connect to SQL that filters within US dates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that the SQL data reader is interpreting your date column as strings instead of dates because Excel spreadsheets do not have any sort of inherent schema so the SQL data reader looks at the values in the first few rows in a particular column to try and infer the data type. Try changing the logic for populating the list box from

```
{
mylistbox.Items.Add(rd[0]);
}
```

to

```
{
  DateTime dt;
  if (!rd[0] is DateTime) {    
    if (DateTime.TryParse(rd[0], out dt) {
        mylistbox.Items.Add(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
  } else {
    mylistbox.Items.Add(rd[0].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
  } 
}
```

The error message suggests that the gridview column that you are trying to filter on is bound to a DateTime value, but the list box you are using to select your filtering value contains a string value (which if you used the code above, it would be). You have not included your code that throws the error, so that is merely an assumption. When you apply the filtering value to the gridview, be sure to convert the filtering value to the correct data type - do not rely on implicit casting to do it for you.